# how to manipulate date- adding days- in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, date, controller

I am facing an issue, I have got one date string like **"15-12-03"** through ng-model **in controller**, how can i **add 20 days or 3 months in to this date string automatically and correctly**,

because I want to make several $http.post call to the server repeatly with different date data, in each call, i need to post a date which is, for example, 20 days later to the previous date in the previous call. The times of repeating can be changed btw, maybe 4 times, maybe 10 times.

I know in the server side, we have a **MOMENT module** which can work like moment.add(20, 'days'). but i dont want to work on the server.js for this manipulating date process, since i dont want to call the datebase several times in one app.post, and i dont know how as well..

anyway, is there anyone know how to add 20 days to a date string "15-12-03" in controller.

regards

Comment: Here 03 means 1903 or 2003 because usually when 2 digits is there then it's for 19th cen..

Comment: it means days three, "15-12-03" == "2015-12-03" == "YY-MM-DD",

Comment: So 90-12-03 means "2090-12-03"?

Comment: the format of date doesnt matter, no matter "YY-MM-DD" or "DD-MM-YY", Its just a format mate

Answer (score 0):

I would first convert the date string to a Date object

```
var dateObject = new Date(yourDateString);
```

Then you can simply manipulate this object, for example like this

```
dateObject = dateObject.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth()+anyNumber);
```

You can read more about the Date class here
[W3C date reference.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

If you need to convert the date object back to a string you can run the `toString()` method.

If you are required to send the date string in a specific format you can create the format you need by fetching the different date values e.g `getMonth(), getFullYear()` etc and build your string to the desired format.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. Actually i dont think setmonth and the Date object can be used in controller. However, I have found a way like, get multiple time in the server side with Moment module, and merge multiple query together and call mysql only one times, it is working now.